# Dynamic number of pages in Watchkit Page Navigation

Tags: swift, watchkit

Is there any way dynamically create pages in a page-based navigation? In every example I read, the pages were created as Interface Controllers and linked in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the way to do it

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["pageController", "pageController"], contexts: ["pageController", "pageController"])
```

Comment: this creates a double spinning animation though, once to load the initial controller, and then again to reload with the new pages.

Comment: Where did you place it? I also get an infinite recursion of pages

Comment: @Erich i agree, but i didn't find anything better at the moment. @edwardmp I placed this code in the default ViewController of the watch interface in the viewDidLoad method. The arrays that i pass as parameters to the `reloadRootControllersWithNames` method should be dynamically generated. I used those just as examples to illustrate the solution.

Comment: use  a static variable to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: Please delete the original solution posted and keep only the update.

Comment: I use two `WKInterfaceController`. Call `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames` from `awakeWithContext` of Initial controller.

Comment: The back button from the status bar goes missing in this case. How do we navigate back to any previous InterfaceController then?

Answer (score 5):

To avoid infinite loop use:

```
static BOOL first = YES;
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];

    if (first) {
        [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SinglePageICIdentifier",@"SinglePageICIdentifier", nil] contexts:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First",@"Second", nil]];
        first = NO;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I presumed you want to display several page of the same kind of data.

[Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW1%20Apple%20Watch%20Programming%20Guide) states the following:

> This style is suited for apps with simple data models where the data on each page is not closely related to the data on any other page.

Therefore, I think you should stick to table views to display several items that are closely related (by kind) to each other. From my point of view, page-based controller navigation (swipe) is too slow / boring to be used for lots of pages. Also, I think it could take a lot of time to load the page-based controller.